# Ruby: sub match groups are nil when it should not

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I am trying to get a credit card number string and mask the middle numbers with asterisks.
I use the regex `/^([\d]{6})([\d]{3,6})([\d]{4})$/` to match three groups:

- First 6 digits
- Middle digits (3 to 6) that will be obfuscated
- Last 4 digits

As you can see from my console below, `gsub` match groups are `nil` at first, until I use a literal string in the replacement attribute. Then when I try to run the initial call, it works.

```
2.0.0-p598 :001 > c = "5454545454545454"
 => "5454545454545454"

2.0.0-p598 :002 > c.gsub(/^([\d]{6})([\d]{3,6})([\d]{4})$/, $1 + '*' * $2.size + $3)
NoMethodError: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/guilherme/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

2.0.0-p598 :003 > c.gsub(/^([\d]{6})([\d]{3,6})([\d]{4})$/, "anything")
 => "anything"

2.0.0-p598 :004 > c.gsub(/^([\d]{6})([\d]{3,6})([\d]{4})$/, $1 + '*' * $2.size + $3)
 => "545454******5454"
```

Why does this happen? Is it a bug? How to fix this and make it work in the first try?

Comment: A bit of advice: post *code*, not *screenshots* of code.

Comment: I guess that the second call to the same code works, because the first call assigns those variables with the matches.

Comment: Further to @Sergio's suggestion, you should post code, rather than a screenshot, so that readers who wish to post an answer can simply cut-and-paste the parts of your code they need.  If you enter `puts 'hi'` in IRB, and the line reads `2.2.0 :053 > puts "hi"`, please do not include `2.2.0 :053 > ` in your question, again, so that readers don't have to strip that off.  Please edit. Also, be sure to assign variables to input data you use in examples (e.g, `arr = [1,2,3]`) so that answers can refer to those variables (e.g, `arr`) without having to define them in terms of the data.

Comment: Finally, posting code as text offers better tag suggestions, syntax highlighting, and search results in Google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For more advanced substitutions such as this one, you should use the block form of `gsub`. Magic variables have values there.

```
s = '1234567890123456'
rgx = /^([\d]{6})([\d]{3,6})([\d]{4})$/

s2 = s.gsub(rgx) do
  $1 + '*' * $2.size + $3
end

s2 # => "123456******3456"
```

(in the non-block form matches are available as `\1`, `\2` and so on. Good for simple substitutions, but you can't call `.size` on them, etc.)

Magic variable are not available in the argument form, because arguments are evaluated **before** invocation of the method. So, variables haven't been set yet. And if you were to call such a method twice, the second time you'll get matches from the first one.

Alternatively, you can avoid all this regex voodoo and just mask characters directly

```
s3 = s.dup # don't touch the original string
s3[6...-4] = '*' * (s.length - 4 - 6) # string of asterisks of variable length
s3  # => "123456******3456"
```

Comment: Mask the characters directly. It's faster and more easily understood and maintained.

Comment: The indices that correspond to the match are not fixed. It may be better to do `6...-4`.

Comment: @sawa: aren't all CC numbers exactly 16 digits long?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I don't know about the reality, but the OP mentions the middle part is 3 to 6.

Comment: I see that it works, but I still don't understand why the block has a different behavior from the method attribute. Besides that, your alternative method looks very simple and straightforward!

Comment: As a side note, some CC have 13 (old Visa) or 15 (Amex) digits rather than the most common 16.

Comment: A couple of small points: you can use `sub` rather than `gsub` and `s2 = s.sub...end` returns `s2`, so you don't have to write `s2 * =>...`. No, some cc numbers [do not have 16 digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: assignment to s2 is there to make `# =>` markers evaluate in textmate. It won't expand if I put at after `end` there.

Comment: @Guilherme: added explanation why magic variables are nil in your case

Answer (score 1):

If you can replace characters in the number, I definitely would go for the solution Sergio Tulentsev suggested. If not :

```
c[0..5] + '*' * (c.size - 10) + c[-4..-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` without capture groups or a block as follows:

```
r = /
    (?<=^.{6}) # match any 6 chars at beginning of string in a positive lookbehind
    .+         # match any number of any character, greedily
    (?=.{4}$)  # match any 4 chars at end of string in a positive lookahead
    /x         # extended option

s.sub(r, '*'*(s.size-10))
  #=> "123456******3456"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without multiplying ' * ' with string size.

```
'1234123412341234'.gsub(/(?<=......).(?=....)/, '*')

=> "123412******1234"
```

Comment: Awesome, complete and simple solution with any string size. :)